# Expire updated CSS and JS files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

We have a site (MVC4 on Azure) on which we change our JS an CSS files occasionally. The updates are not scheduled and some times - quite often. I don't want to go into IIS and change settings or work with header files that have countless references to files and dates.

Currently, we are changing the file names but you can imagine how much work it requires.

Some time ago I read that we can expire these files on demand by keeping the file names of the files that change often in one file and whenever anything on that file changes, the browser is forced to reload those files.

Is this something I should do and how?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add version numbers to files that changed. You can read the actual version with php, and append it to the modified filenames automatically.

Version sample code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?v=12345678" />
```

This forces the browser to download the files again.

Comment: I think this is a workaround and I am looking for the above mentioned solution. Thanks though!